# i am insert write php code some error logo and image

Tags: php

I want to insert some data using PHP 7.2 table name **seller_login** and field **user_id, username, password, type_login, image, logo** PHP insert in a script. not working. always **logo and image** about error show please help me

[image: ![enter image description here]

**show error here**

```
Notice: Undefined index: logo in D:\xammp\htdocs\multivender\myhomeportal\seller-register.php on line 94

Notice: Undefined index: logo in D:\xammp\htdocs\multivender\myhomeportal\seller-register.php on line 94

Notice: Undefined index: image in D:\xammp\htdocs\multivender\myhomeportal\seller-register.php on line 95

Notice: Undefined index: image in D:\xammp\htdocs\multivender\myhomeportal\seller-register.php on line 95
```

**PHP code line number like 94**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]

  ["tmp_name"],"../sellerimage/$user_id/".$_FILES["logo"]["name"]);
```

**PHP code line number like 95**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]

["tmp_name"],"../sellerimage/$user_id/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

**PHP all script here**

```
<?php
    $username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
    $username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";
    $type_login = $type_err = $type_login = "";
    $logo = $logo_err = $logo='';
    $image = $image_err = $image='';

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
            $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
        } else{
            $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM  seller_login WHERE username = ?";

            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

                $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                        $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                    } else{
                        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                    }
                } else{
                    echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }

            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
        //------------------------
             if(empty(trim($_POST["type_login"]))){
                    $type_err = "Please Select User Type.";     
             } else{
                    $type_login = trim($_POST["type_login"]);
                }
        //------------grant----------------


        //------------------------
        if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
            $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
        } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
            $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
        } else{
            $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
        }

        if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
            $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
        } else{
            $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
            if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
                $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
            }
        }
        //-------------------seller logo insert------------------------

        if(empty($_FILES["logo"]["name"])){$logo_err = "Please Select Logo.";} 
        else{ $logo =$_FILES["logo"]["name"];}
        //-------------------image---------------------------

        if(empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])){$image_err = "Please Select image.";} 
        else{$image =$_FILES["image"]["name"];}

        //--------------------directory creation for Seller images---------------

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select max(user_id) as pid from seller_login");
        $result=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $sellerid=$result['pid']+1;
        $dir="../sellerimage/$sellerid";
        mkdir($dir);// directory creation for Seller images
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"],"../sellerimage/$sellerid/".$_FILES["logo"]["name"]);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"../sellerimage/$sellerid/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]);




        //----------------------------------------------------------------

        if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO seller_login (username, password, type_login, logo, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $param_username, $param_password, $type_login, $logo, $image);

                $param_username = $username;

                $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 

                if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                    $msg="Successfully Login";      
                } else{
                     $msg="Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
    ?>
```

**HTML form**

```
<form style="border: 2px solid #28a745;" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                                <div class="row text-center ">
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8"><h3 class="btn-success p-2">Please fill this form to create an account.</h3></div>
                                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                </div></br> 

                                <!----------------Username---------------->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><b>Username</b></div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" offset>
                                            <span class="help-block"style="color: #ff0000;text-align:center;"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
                                        </div> 

                                        <div class="col-md-2"><b>Password</b></div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                                            <span class="help-block" style="color: #ff0000;text-align:center;"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                                    </div>
                                <!-------------Password------------------->


                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><b>Confirm Password</b></div>

                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                                            <span class="help-block" style="color: #ff0000;text-align:center;"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><b>Select User Type</b></div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 <?php echo (!empty($type_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                            <select  name="type_login"  class="form-control">
                                                <option value="">Select</option>
                                                <option value="1">Add Seller</option>
                                            </select>
                                           <span class="help-block" style="color: #ff0000;text-align:center;"><?php echo $type_err; ?></span>
                                        </div>


                                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                                    </div>


                                 <!------------Select picture------------>                          
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                                        <div class="col-md-2"><b>Profile Picture</b></div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 <?php echo (!empty($image_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control p-0" value="<?php echo $image; ?>">
                                            <span class="help-block"style="color: #ff0000;text-align:center;"><?php echo $image_err; ?></span>
                                        </div> 

                                        <div class="col-md-2"><b>Company Logo</b></div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3 <?php echo (!empty($logo_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                            <input type="file" name="logo" class="form-control p-0" value="<?php echo $logo; ?>">
                                            <span class="help-block" style="color: #ff0000;text-align:center;"><?php echo $logo_err; ?></span>
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <hr><hr>
                                    <!----------------------------->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-5"></div>

                                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                             <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"size="40" style="cursor: pointer;">Insert</button>
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
                                        </div> 
                                        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                    </div>  

                                </form>
```

Comment: please check it and share this write php edit  code sir

Comment: sir, please check it my problem different and user id and IP different  so please help me..

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: logo` <- this is your "error" - which isn't an error, but a warning. Also it means, that the key logo doesn't exist in the array you're trying to access. Setup debugging and var_dump's throughout your script to resolve your issue.

Comment: but allwase image and logo blank error show

Comment: image and logo do not insert in a database sir

Comment: What these warnings are telling you, is that `$_FILES["logo"]` and `$_FILES["image"]` are not set at all - so you have _not_ correctly uploaded any files under these two parameter names to begin with.

Comment: please share edit code sir

Comment: We would need to see the form which is supposed to perform this upload - which you have not even shown us yet. (Meaning the HTML code, not a screenshot of what it _looks like_.)

Comment: sir, I am sharing this HTML form, please check it sir

Comment: This is missing the correct `enctype` on the form. https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use enctype when u open form (enctype="multipart/form-data):

```
<form style="border: 2px solid #28a745;" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```